# Problem capturing the searched results using wire:model in a searchable input text

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I am implementing a searchable input text that displays the results well, the problem is when a user types like anc the results i select is anchorage but when I dd the results in livewire I get anc. the ajax code

```
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "/searchcity",
    success: function (response) {
      townsTags = response;
      startAutocomplete(townsTags, "#search_towns");
    }
  });

  function startAutocomplete(availableTags, inputSelector) {
    $(inputSelector).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
```

}

The A section of livewire class

```
    public $search_towns;

    public function addBusinessData(){

       dd($this->search_towns);
}
```

in the livewire component I have

```
 <form wire:submit.prevent="addBusinessData">
  <div class="col">
    <input class="form-control" type="search" wire:model="search_towns" 
    id="search_towns" name= "search_towns" autocomplete="off" 
    placeholder="Select City/Town "/> 
   <span class="text-danger">@error('search_towns'){{ $message 
   }}@enderror</span>
 </div>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary m-4">   
  </form>
```

Comment: Where is the Livewire code? this is jQuery. Also I can't see any dd() here

Comment: @Pippo, thanks for the response I have added the livewire section

Comment: You do not specify whether autocomplete occurs in the browser. Anyway the problem is that jQuery probably updates the field in the browser, but Livewire uses internal variables to hold the values ​​and only updates them with the values ​​you type.
In my personal opinion, mixing different techniques should be avoided and I would implement the autocomplete with Livewire and Alpine. If you want to stick with it your way, you need to access the component data using the [Livewire object](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/javascript#the-livewire-global-object)

Comment: If you google with "Livewire autocomplete" you can find many resources